# Word for an object within another object

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that defines an object or thing within another object or thing.

Like in the movie *Inception*: a dream within a dream.

Comment: There are bound to be several answers which would work better in one context than another - One of my faves (often used sarcastically) is: "creamy filling". (I think it's a "Twinkie" thing.) (US)

Comment: Yo Dawg! I heard you like words in your words...

Comment: "Droste Effect". Read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droste_effect

Comment: Even when limited to the field of computer programming there are probably a dozen different terms that might describe this concept, depending on the specific context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recursive might be what you are after.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: Thank you :) All the above answered are great but i think this is the word i was looking for.

Comment: Fun fact, type "Recursion" into Google search and it asks "Did you mean: recursion"

Answer (score 19):

I would use *[nested](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nested)*.  For example, "a dream *nested* within another dream".

See, for example, [Russian nesting dolls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll).

Comment: I feel that this is better suited compared to recursion.

Answer (score 7):

The best word will depend on the context. Given the example of a dream within a dream, I assume that you're thinking of a distinct object that is inside another object, not an object which is a part of another object.

An object that is inside another object can be said to be ***[embedded](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embed#English)***. The inner object can be of the same type as the outer object or of a different type. Some examples of usage include:

- A pole is *embedded* in the ground: it's inserted in the ground and can't be removed easily.
- An *embedded journalist* is one who belongs to the team that he's reporting on, for example an army reporter who is part of an army unit.
- A computer document that is *embedded* in another computer document is stored in the same file and displayed as part of the larger document, for example a picture in a word processor document.
- In linguistics, *embedding* refers to the ability to build up clauses that are part of a sentence. [*Recursion*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/5875/whats-the-difference-between-recursion-and-embedding) is embedding of a clause inside a clause of the same form.

Answer (score 2):

[Subset](http://www.yourdictionary.com/subset):

> Subset is defined as a portion, particularly in mathematics. *An example of subset is a classroom to an entire school.*

[Component](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/component):

> a constituent part or aspect of something more complex

*Constituent*, subunit, part...

Answer (score 2):

How about [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mise%20en%20abyme) from Merriam Webster

> ### Mise en abyme
>
> - placement at the center of an escutcheon of a smaller copy of the same escutcheon
> - containment of an entity within another identical entity
> - image of an image

And from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mise_en_abyme), how mise en abyme is used in film:

> Mise-en-abîme occurs within a text when there is a reduplication of images or concepts referring to the textual whole.[...] In film, the meaning of "mise en abyme" is similar to the artistic definition, but also includes the idea of a "dream within a dream". For example, a character awakens from a dream and later discovers that s/he is still dreaming.

The article on Wikipedia specifically mentions Inception as an example of this.

Answer (score 1):

[**Inclusion**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inclusion):

> A person or thing that is included within a whole

This is also used commonly in science, for example:

- In set theory, a smaller set is **included** in a larger, more comprehensive set.
- In geology, a smaller rock is **included** in a larger rock.